# MS Deploy package to IIS site with custom path

Tags: iis, iis-7, msdeploy, web-deployment

I have a package I created from an IIS 6 site and I want to deploy it to IIS7 but I dont want to use the path specified in the package (it doesn't exist on target). How do I deploy the package with a new path?

- Is there a switch I can specify, such as an additional -dest?
- Is there something I have to do when creating the pacakge to set the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here http://raquila.com/software/ms-deploy-basics/ at the very bottom. You have to use a replace switch

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package=c:\pkg.zip -dest:metakey=lm/w3svc/2 -replace:objectName=metaProperty,match="c:\\path1",replace="c:\\path2"
```